# While inside of onCreated gets stuck on a array in PowerShell but works fine in ISE

Tags: powershell, while-loop, file-watcher

Wrote a script that monitors a folder for new files.  When onCreated is called it increments to the next drive letter in my list, then checks that drive for free space.  If the free space is under my requirement it increments again.  My full script works great in ISE.

Here is a simplified version that I still can't get to work.
When ran in PowerShell and it gets stuck on `$DriveVar` and only outputs "marker1".  If you run in ISE the marker2 line correctly rotates through the drive letters for each file you copy into the folder.

```
$filter = '*.*'
$Watchfolder = "C:\Script\watch"
$LocationArray = "L","J","K","Q","S"
$LocationCount = [int]$LocationArray.Count
$LastUsed = [int]0

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Watchfolder, $filter -Property @{
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite' }

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $Freespace = [long]-1
    while ($Freespace -le 0) {
        $LastUsed++
        if ($LastUsed -ge $LocationCount) {
            $LastUsed = 0 }
        Write-Host "marker1"

        $DriveVar = $LocationArray[$LastUsed]
        Write-Host "marker2 $DriveVar"
        $Freespace = 5
    }
}
```

Output in PowerShell:

```
marker1
```

Output in ISE:

```
marker1
marker2 J
marker1
marker2 K
marker1
marker2 Q
```

I tried calling a function for `$DriveVar` and some other things (all working in ISE) and I can't seem to make it work.  And if I use the while loop on its own (without the onCreated) it works fine in Powershell.

Comment: If you close the ISE, and then re-launch it and run the script, does it still work fine in the ISE? If so this may be a STA vs MTA issue, and we can probably work with that.

Comment: "If you close the ISE, and then re-launch it and run the script, does it still work fine in the ISE"   Just tested and yes.

Comment: Try launching powershell.exe with the `-Mta` argument, and see if your script still hangs when run like that.

Comment: I tried both -Mta and -Sta (wasn't sure what default was) still hangs in same spot.

Comment: This on 2012R2 / PS4.0 but also tested on Win7 / PS3.0 and same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a matter of scope. I did a little testing on my end using your code and got the same results. I was able to fix things by scoping the variables to `$global:`, and then got the desired results. Try this out:

```
$filter = '*.*'
$Watchfolder = "C:\Script\watch"
$global:LocationArray = "L","J","K","Q","S"
$global:LocationCount = [int]$LocationArray.Count
$global:LastUsed = [int]0

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Watchfolder, $filter -Property @{
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite' }

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $Freespace = [long]-1
    while ($Freespace -le 0) {
        $global:LastUsed++
        if ($global:LastUsed -ge $global:LocationCount) {
            $global:LastUsed = 0 }
        Write-Host "marker1"

        $DriveVar = $global:LocationArray[$global:LastUsed]
        Write-Host "marker2 $DriveVar"
        $Freespace = 5
    }
}
```

I found this by just trying to `Write-Host $LocationArray` after your `Write-Host "marker1"` line, and it just spit out a blank line.

Comment: Sweet thanks that fixed it!  Something else hanging up my full script now but I'm sure I just need to make some others global.

Answer (score 0):

We know globals are frowned upon, but for your use case, set your drive, count, lastused as globals and this works as shown below.

```
$filter = '*.*'
$Watchfolder = "D:\Scripts\watch"

$Global:LocationArray = "L","J","K","Q","S"
$Global:LocationCount = [int]$LocationArray.Count
$Global:LastUsed = [int]0

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Watchfolder, $filter -Property @{
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite' }

# Clear previous event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $Freespace = [long]-1
    while ($Freespace -le 0) {
        $LastUsed++
        if ($LastUsed -ge $LocationCount) 
        { $LastUsed = 0 }
        Write-Host "marker1"

        $DriveVar = $LocationArray[$LastUsed]
        Write-Host "marker2 $DriveVar"
        $Freespace = 5
    }
}
```

... in the ISE

```
 marker1
marker2 J
marker1
marker2 K
marker1
marker2 Q
```

... In the console host

```
 marker1
marker2 J
marker1
marker2 K
marker1
marker2 Q
```